# How to match digit in middle of a string efficiently in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings like

```
XXX-1234
XXXX-1234
XX - 4321
ABCDE - 4321
AB -5677
```

So there will be letters at the beginning. then there will be hyphen. and then 4 digits. Number of letters may vary but number of digits are same = 4

Now I need to match the first 2 positions from the digits. So I tried a long process.

```
temp_digit=mystring;
temp_digit=temp_digit.replace(/ /g,'');
temp_digit=temp_digit.split("-");
if(temp_digit[1].substring(0,2)=='12') {}
```

Now is there any process using regex / pattern matching so that I can do it in an efficient way. Something like [string.match(regexp)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) I'm dumb in regex patterns. How can I find the first two digits from 4 digits from above strings ? Also it would be great it the solution can match digits without hyphens like `XXX 1234` But this is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> may vary but number of digits are same = 4
>   Now I need to match the first 2 positions from the digits.
>
> > Also it would be great it the solution can match digits without hyphens like `XXX 1234` But this is optional.

Do you really need to check it starts with letters? How about matching ANY 4 digit number, and capturing only the first 2 digits?

**Regex**

```
/\b(\d{2})\d{2}\b/
```

Matches:

- `\b` a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(\d{2})` 2 digits, [captured in group 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and assigned to `match[1]`.
- `\d{2}` 2 more digits (not captured).
- `\b` a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

**Code**

```js
var regex = /\b(\d{2})\d{2}\b/;
var str = 'ABCDE 4321';
 
var result = str.match(regex)[1];

document.body.innerText += result;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Try a regular expression that finds at least one letter `[a-zA-Z]+`, followed by some space if necessary `\s*`, followed by a hyphen `-`, followed by some more space if necessary `\s*`. It then matches the first two digits `\d{2}` after the pattern.:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s*-\s*(\d{2})
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your answer. It works. Mariano's answer met my optional criteria too.

Answer (score 0):

If there are always 4 digits at the end, you can simply slice it:

```
str.trim().slice(-4,-2);
```

here's a jsfiddle with the example strings:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/6suffmmm/

Comment: It's not a good idea, as any dumb user may enter a space at the end by mistake. I want to avoid the exact positioning number.